# Grouping dates for each period

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

Everyday an employee is sick, a record is added
My table looks like this (example):

```
Name   -   Date  
Ben   -   14/01/2016   
Ben   -   15/01/2016  
Ben   -   18/01/2016  
Ben   -   19/01/2016  
Ben   -   02/02/2016  
Ben   -   03/02/2016  
Bart  -   12/01/2016  
Bart  -   13/01/2016  
Bart  -   14/01/2016
Lisa  -   26/02/2016  
Lisa  -   29/02/2016  
Lisa  -   01/03/2016
```

What I need is:

```
Name   -   StartDate   -  NumberOfDays  
Ben   -   14/01/2016   -   4 (so 4 following dates (including a weekend))  
Ben   -   02/02/2016   -   2  
Bart   -  12/01/2016   -   3  
Lisa  -  26/02/2016    -   3
```

So grouped by name and period, and show the start date and number of days of the period.

I have no idea how to start and even if it's possible in SQL.

The problem is that the period can include weekends so I think I need a **table weekend dates and holidays** to check (because by just taking ==> `(difference current.date-previous.date) <= 3` will possible make one period of the actual two periods when the 3 days are not a weekend)?

I hope I explained my problem well. All help is highly appreciated!

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server have different date/time handling. Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: What about National holidays?

Comment: If you have a time table, add another column to it which will rank each row and filter weekends, that way the rank column will be continuously

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the reply, I deleted the tags,
National holidays should also be seen as holiday (same as weekend)
But I have a table with all weekend days and holidays

Comment: @sagi I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Let's introduce kind of function GET_NEXT_DATE(date). You can pass a date and get next one

Like this.

    `CASE getDayOfWeek(date) 
      WHEN friday THEN date + 3 days 
      ELSE date + 1 day
    END `

Real implementation depends on DB you use.

Comment: Add (Lisa, 31/12/2015) and (Lisa, 01/01/2016) or similar to your sample data!

Comment: @StanislavL Thanks, I'm using MS Access for the moment, not sure how to implement that function in my query, also It would be better if I could compare date with table holidays,

Comment: @jarlh the data sets or seperated by year, so table sickdays 2015, seperate table sickdays 2016

Comment: Alright, add (Lisa, 29/2/2016) and (Lisa, 1/3/2016), just to make it a bit trickier.

Comment: What engine are you using? please tag accordingly

Answer (score 0):

MS Access? I doubt that this can easily be solved with MS Access SQL alone, but I don't know it well enough to be sure.

What you would do is cross-join all sick users with all none-working days. Use this result in union with the sick days. Then the whole thing becomes a mere gaps and island problem. Usually best solved with analytic functions, which I am pretty sure MS Access doesn't feature.

This would be the working base:

```
select s.name, n.date, 'NO WORK DAY'
from (select distinct name from sick) s
cross join noneworkdays n
union all
select s.name, s.date, 'SICK'
from sick s;
```

Another option is to select all sick days and all none-working days and use a programming language to solve this in a loop. This may be the easiest solution for you.

Answer (score -4):

This is for SQL Server:

```
select Name, min(Date), count(*), Year(Date), Month(Date)
from table
group by Name, Year(Date), Month(Date)
```

Other databases will have equivalent functions to YEAR() and MONTH().

Comment: this is not what op ask. You'll bring just one row for Ben

Comment: I think this is what OP asked. It will being one row per year/month for Ben.

Comment: op ask for continuos days

Comment: This won't work, what will happen if he work in the same month, but took a few days sick, it won't know since you are group by month and year and it doesn't matter if he have gaps in this month(also if he worked with no gaps between feb and march, both should be counted as one)

Comment: I see apossible reading of the question to give that answer, but my reading is possible also. It's not exactly defined very closely. But OK, obviously people think I've read it wrong.